# How do i grab the eject key in a x11 app (yeahconsole)

Tags: c, linux, x11

I'm trying to modify [yeahconsole](http://phrat.de/yeahtools.html) to show on pressing the eject key, I tried XF86XK_Eject, Eject, XK_Eject and other combinations and it does not seem to work.

here the xev output  for the key code

```
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
root 0xbb, subw 0x0, time 5629995, (162,-8), root:(1183,516),
state 0x0, keycode 169 (keysym 0x1008ff2c, XF86Eject), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

and heres the c code

https://github.com/jagguli/yeahconsole/blob/master/yeahconsole.c

Comment: XF86XK_Eject is correct according to /usr/include/X11/XF86keysym.h.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: In the code line 249 if I set the key to anything else like None+F12 it works but None+XF86XK_Eject as @parkydr mentioned it doesn't seem to register.

Comment: Now I've looked at line 249, you should use XF86Eject as it's a string. Look at the return value from XGrabKey, you may be getting a BadAccess error because something else (probably the window manager) has grabbed it already.

Comment: Looks like im getting a return value of 1 which maps to BadRequest ?

Comment: A lot of xlib functions return 1 when ok, your error handling routine should probably have caught the error anyway.

Comment: yea I think its kde interfering, just tried using dwm at work computer and it works.